# Can we delete folders from spool by the legacy way with rm -rf

Tags: rhel, find, abrt

We have the following folders

```
ls -ltr /var/spool/

abrt

drwx------. 2 root root 4096 Mar 11 16:53 ccpp-2020-03-11-15:41:35-1574876666
drwx------. 2 root root 4096 Mar 11 16:53 ccpp-2020-03-11-15:47:52-3964344561
drwx------. 2 root root 4096 Mar 11 16:53 ccpp-2020-03-11-16:00:03-7828477646
drwx------. 2 root root 4096 Mar 11 16:53 ccpp-2020-03-11-16:24:33-1454958470
```

we try to delete the folders with

```
find /var/spool/abrt/  -type d -ctime +10  -exec abrt-cli rm '{}' \;
```

but `abrt-cli` not delete them

my question , can we delete them without abrt-cli as ( after stop the abrt service )

```
 find /var/spool/abrt/  -type d -ctime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Possibly related [What is the right approach to purge /var/spool/abrt/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556307/what-is-the-right-approach-to-purge-var-spool-abrt)

Comment: this link isnt answer what I asked